# How to check if specific columns in a wpf datagrid are empty while implementing MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm trying to build a Windows UI using WPF while also implementing MVVM. There is a DataGrid that is placed that gets data from a equipment list. I also have a button at the bottom of the UI that is to remain hidden until specific columns in each row are filled, such as columns 1,3,and 4 of each row. I can worry about the visibility of the button later but I need help with searching the columns. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is the `DataGrid` bound to a model of some sort? If so, what properties of the model are those and columns and rows associated with. When the model is in the desired state then have a flag in your view model that gets set to true and bind your button's visibility to that flag.

Comment: DataGrid gets its data from an List which is populated by a equipment model. The properties of Equipment model are EquipID, EquipName, Lat, and Long. I only care if the EquipID, Lat and Long are filled. Not sure if this answers the question or not. Due to sensitivity of the code, I cannot post it.